# Is the Azure Video Indexer SDK Discontinued?

Tags: azure, artificial-intelligence, azure-cognitive-services

I'm currently looking for documentation on how to use the Azure Video Indexer SDK for python and I'm unable to find anything. What I am able to find is documentation on how to use the API.

Is anyone aware if the Azure Video Indexer SDK is discontinued? If not, where can I look for documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SDK is supported. I don't see any pyhton specific documentation, however that is not unusual. All Azure services are meant to have client SDKs for multiple languages including python. These SDKs are generated by the REST API swagger and exposed as part of the larger [Azure SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python). I believe this is the source code for the Azure Video indexer SDK https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/cognitiveservices/azure-cognitiveservices-search-videosearch

Writing docs takes a lot of time, especially if there are multiple SDK platforms/code languages. The API interface of Azure SDKs generally closely align with the REST API interfaces. As such, Azure engineering teams tend to focus more on core features/functionalities than documenting the different SDKs since the existing REST API docs can often be a good enough guide, especially when combined with the additional learning materials such as these: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/analyze-video/